# Moving Laravel 5.1 website from localhost to web host

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

My Laravel 5.1 website works fine on my localhost. I moved all folders to a "laravel" folder I created off root at the host. Host is running php 5.6. Then moved the index.php (originally in the laravel public folder) to public_html at the host. Made some edits to the index.php for it to see bootstrap. I could see the front login page, and at that point it's not making any calls to the database. My next step was to run artisan migrations to create the database and seed it. When I ran:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

I got this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/myself9/laravel/artisan on line 31

and that line happens to be:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
```

I verified that the required php extensions are installed with my host's php rev 5.6

OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: did you run `composer install` after moving your files to host?

Comment: No, I didn't do that. Is it necessary? what will composer install do?

Comment: It is necessary, as laravel commands will not work if laravel framework is not installed. However, this might be a partial solution to the problem. Please go ahead and try and let me know what happens after that

Comment: baboobi8@serv01 [~/laravel]# composer install
-bash: composer: command not found. I connected to my host web using SSH, and issued composer install from the same folder where I saw file "composer.json"

Comment: Good that you have SSH-ed. Follow my answer and we can debug further if the problem persists .

Answer (score 3):

Okay, based on your last comment, I see that even composer isn't installed. You will have to Install composer using cURL in your shared host. Use the command below

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

(I hope that php is pre installed in your host)

Now, go to the directory where `composer.json` and `composer.lock` are located and run `composer install` this will install all the dependecies your project has.

As I said, this may be a partial solution but these are initial things that you need to do after moving your project to server. I will update this answer based on your further comments..

**EDIT**

If your server is a shared host, you will not be allowed to run composer directly. Move `composer.phar` that you downloaded using cURL to your project root and run `php composer.phar install`

Comment: baboobi8@serv01 [~/laravel]# curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The detect_unicode setting must be disabled.
Add the following to the end of your `php.ini`:
    detect_unicode = Off

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: /usr/local/php53/lib/php.ini
If you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d option=value` to modify ini values on the fly. You can use -d multiple times.

Comment: Follow as it says. Try running `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off`

Comment: Seems like it worked. See below please.


baboobi8@serv01 [~]# curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=off
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

PHP was compiled with --with-curlwrappers which will cause issues with HTTP authentication and GitHub.
Recompile it without this flag if possible

Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /home/baboobi8/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar

Comment: for your reference, laravel files (which work fine on my localhost) i moved them all to host folder /home/baboobi8/laravel/   that's where I see files composer.json and composer.lock. I went there and ran composer install, but it didn't work, it said composer command not found. I tried php composer install and still did not work --> could not open input file composer.

Comment: go to the directory where your composer.json is and run `php composer.phar install`

Comment: You will have to move your `composer.phar` file to the same directory where your `composer.json` is, and run `php composer.phar install`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97806/discussion-between-soltan-and-vishal-sh).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a cronjob like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/YOUR_USER/domains/YOUR_DOMAIN/artisan migrate:refresh >> /dev/null 2>&1
```